# Can't enter Ubuntu 12.04 after installing Windows on a separate partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I've installed Windows on a separate partition than Ubuntu, but now I can't enter Ubuntu -- it just automatically boots to Windows.

What should I do to gain the ability to choose my operating system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must repair the grub (windows has corrupted it). You can easy do this with de boot-repair disc.  Boot with this disc, and let repair the system automatically.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair .  Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I take it you installed Windows **after** Ubuntu.  Windows doesn't know about (or care about) other operating systems, unlike Linux.  So, it automatically installs its bootloader in the MBR.

I think the easiest way is to get the [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), which can fix this automatically.  It's saved me many times in the past.  It can be done with the original Ubuntu install disk, too.  The basic task is to install grub back into the MBR, and tell it to look at the Ubuntu partition for its menu.  It's a little more involved doing it this way, though.

Comment: Can I install boot repair in windows ? Or do I have to boot it from a cd or usb ?

Comment: It's a bootable disk, which is a small version of Linux, if I remember correctly.  It will find the operating systems on the hard drive, and repair the grub boot loader for all of them.